# Solr5.4 indexing using DataImportHandler

Tags: join, solr5, dih

I am using Solr 5.4. Working on indexing entities using Data Import Handler which are having inner joins and left joins as below.

Does solr5.4 supports inner joins and left joins?

I am having a query which has relationship between 7 tables. I am doing inner joins for few and left joins for few tables.

Any help is highly appreciated!!